# Error during npm install on a React.js project

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I posted another question on the same issue a few weeks ago, but got nothing. So posting again...

I keep getting the following error during `npm install`. Any help on how to fix it would be highly appreciated.

I'm on:

Ubuntu 20.04LTS

node v14.4.0

node-gyp v5.1.0

Here's the error log:

```
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/client_load_reporting_filter.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb_channel_secure.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb_client_stats.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.o
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:495,
                 from ../deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb.h:68,
                 from ../deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_decode.h:9,
                 from ../deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.cc:21:
In function ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘grpc_grpclb_request* grpc_grpclb_request_create(const char*)’ at ../deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.cc:70:10:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:106:34: error: ‘char* __builtin_strncpy(char*, const char*, long unsigned int)’ specified bound 128 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
  106 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [grpc.target.mk:494: Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-39-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v14.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-39-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.20.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-06-25T06_32_12_353Z-debug.log
```

Thanks!

Comment: hey can you try `npm cache clean --force` and try to install again?

Comment: Did you copy the code from somewhere?  `/home/user/path/to/app/node_modules/grpc/build`

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan yes, it's my work repository. I'm trying to open the app locally, but keep getting the error.

Comment: Do you have a `/path/to/app` at wherever you're building

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan that part's just a placeholder for the sake of this question.

Comment: You may be able to avoid this error by using a more recent version of `grpc` that has precompiled binaries for Node 14, such as the latest version, 1.24.4. Alternatively, if you are using `grpc` directly, you can replace it with `@grpc/grpc-js`, which does not have this issue.